# Counting open files per process

Tags: linux, bash, ps

I'm working on an application that monitors the processes' resources and gives a periodic report in Linux, but I faced a problem in extracting the open files count per process.

This takes quite a while if I take all of the files and group them according to their PID and count them.

**How can I take the open files count for each process in Linux?**

Comment: you need lsof : `man lsof`

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Have a look at the `/proc/` file system:

```
ls /proc/$pid/fd/ | wc -l
```

To do this for all processes, use this:

```
cd /proc
for pid in [0-9]*
do
    echo "PID = $pid with $(ls /proc/$pid/fd/ | wc -l) file descriptors"
done
```

As a one-liner (filter by appending `| grep -v "0 FDs"`):

```
for pid in /proc/[0-9]*; do printf "PID %6d has %4d FDs\n" $(basename $pid) $(ls $pid/fd | wc -l); done
```

As a one-liner including the command name, sorted by file descriptor count in descending order (limit the results by appending `| head -10`):

```
for pid in /proc/[0-9]*; do p=$(basename $pid); printf "%4d FDs for PID %6d; command=%s\n" $(ls $pid/fd | wc -l) $p "$(ps -p $p -o comm=)"; done | sort -nr
```

Credit to @Boban for this addendum:

> You can pipe the output of the script above into the following script to see the ten processes (and their names) which have the most file descriptors open:

```
  ...
done | sort -rn -k5 | head | while read -r _ _ pid _ fdcount _
do
  command=$(ps -o cmd -p "$pid" -hc)
  printf "pid = %5d with %4d fds: %s\n" "$pid" "$fdcount" "$command"
done
```

Here's another approach to list the top-ten processes with the most open fds, probably less readable, so I don't put it in front:

```
find /proc -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '[0-9]*' \
     -exec bash -c "ls {}/fd/ | wc -l | tr '\n' ' '" \; \
     -printf "fds (PID = %P), command: " \
     -exec bash -c "tr '\0' ' ' < {}/cmdline" \; \
     -exec echo \; | sort -rn | head
```

Comment: it gives me an error :"cannot access /proc/$pid/fd/: no such file or directoy "

Comment: What is your `$pid`?  You know shell variables, don't you?

Comment: Try with `ls /proc/$$/fd/ | wc -l` first.  `$$` evaluates to your current shell; that should always exist of course.

Comment: I would like to obtain the count of all running processes , not only one .

Comment: Of course, you will need to have root permissions to do that for many of the processes.  Their file descriptors are kind of private, you know ;-)

Comment: /proc/$pid/fd lists descriptor files, that is slightly different of "open files" as we can have memory map and other unusual file objects.

Comment: This extends the answer and turns pids to command names:       `for pid in [0-9]*; do echo "PID = $pid with $(ls /proc/$pid/fd/ 2>/dev/null | wc -l) file descriptors"; done | sort -rn -k5 | head | while read -r line; do pid=`echo $line | awk '{print $3}'`; command=`ps -o cmd -p $pid -hc`; echo $line | sed -s "s/PID = \(.*\) with \(.*\)/Command $command (PID = \1) with \2/g"; done`

Comment: Thanks, @BobanP.!  I adopted your extension and added it to my answer.

Comment: also add `2>dev/null` to `ls /proc/$pid/fd/` to avoid printing errors on stderr for shortlived processes `ls: cannot access /proc/38391/fd/: No such file or directory`

Comment: Yeah, well.  Instead of parsing the original output and then call `ps` again for each process to find out its command, it might make more sense to use `/proc/$pid/cmdline` in the first loop.  While technically it is still possible for a process to disappear between the evaluating of `[0-9]*` and the scanning of its disc, this is less likely.

Comment: @BobanP. I added another approach using `find`.

Comment: Executing `command=$(ps -o cmd -p "$pid" -hc)` gave me `Warning: bad syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'`. It worked running as `command=$(ps -o cmd -p "$pid" hc)`.

Comment: @LucasBasquerotto Without the dash it worked for me as well (Ubuntu 18.04, `ps` version 3.3.10) so maybe that's a bit more portable.  In fact my manpage doesn't mention `-h` at all which also indicates that omitting the dash might be preferable.

Comment: The second block of code works great. The third block is doing something wrong because I get wildly different numbers.

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
ps aux | sed 1d | awk '{print "fd_count=$(lsof -p " $2 " | wc -l) && echo " $2 " $fd_count"}' | xargs -I {} bash -c {}
```

Comment: For Fedora, it gives:
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: no pwd entry for UID 65535

Answer (score 7):

I used this to find top filehandler-consuming processes for a given user (username) where dont have lsof or root access:

```
for pid in `ps -o pid -u username` ; do echo "$(ls /proc/$pid/fd/ 2>/dev/null | wc -l ) for PID: $pid" ; done  | sort -n | tail
```

Answer (score 7):

> How can I take the open files count for each process in Linux?

```
procpath query -f stat,fd
```

if you're running it from root (e.g. prefixing the command with `sudo -E env PATH=$PATH`), otherwise it'll only return file descriptor counts per process whose `/proc/{pid}/fd` you may list. This will give you a big JSON document/tree whose nodes look something like:

```json
{
  "fd": {
    "anon": 3,
    "blk": 0,
    "chr": 1,
    "dir": 0,
    "fifo": 0,
    "lnk": 0,
    "reg": 0,
    "sock": 3
  },
  "stat": {
    "pid": 25649,
    "ppid": 25626,
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

The content of `fd` dictionary is counts per file descriptor type. The most interesting ones are probably these (see [procfile.Fd](https://procpath.readthedocs.io/en/stable/procfs.html#procpath.procfile.Fd) description or [man fstat](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fstat) for more details):

- `reg` – count of open (regular) files
- `sock` – count of open sockets

I'm the author of [Procpath](https://pypi.org/project/Procpath/), which is a tool that provides a nicer interface to procfs for process analysis. You can record a process tree's procfs stats (in a SQLite database) and plot any of them later. For instance this is how my Firefox's process tree (root PID 2468) looks like with regards to open file descriptor count (sum of all types):

```
procpath --logging-level ERROR record -f stat,fd -i 1 -d ff_fd.sqlite \ 
  '$..children[?(@.stat.pid == 2468)]'
# Ctrl+C
procpath plot -q fd -d ff_fd.sqlite -f ff_df.svg
```

[image: Firefox open file descriptors]

If I'm interested in only a particular type of open file descriptors (say, sockets) I can plot it like this:

```
procpath plot --custom-value-expr fd_sock -d ff_fd.sqlite -f ff_df.svg
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
ps -opid= -ax | xargs -L 1 -I{} -- sudo bash -c 'echo -n "{} ";lsof -p {} 2>/dev/null | wc -l' | sort -n -k2
```

It prints `numopenfiles` per `pid` sorted by `numopenfiles`.

It will ask for sudo password once.

Note that the sum of the above numbers might be bigger than the total number of open files from all processes.
As I read here: [forked processes can share file handles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/104405)